# ReferenceError: card is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

Please i need help on this. I am using stipe elements form , and while it is displaying on development, it does not display on heroku production and this is the error Inspect Element is giving me =>

### ReferenceError: Card is not defined

i have no idea, so need help please.

i am on Ruby 2.3 & Rails 5.2.3

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  const public_key = document.querySelector("meta[name='stripe-public-key']").content;
  const stripe = Stripe(public_key);
  const elements = stripe.elements();

  const style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '32px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '18px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

  const card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  card.mount('#card-element');

  card.addEventListener('change', ({error}) => {
    const displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (error) {
      displayError.textContent = error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });


  const form = document.getElementById('new_job');
    form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const {token, error} = await stripe.createToken(card);

    if (error) {
      // Inform the customer that there was an error.
      const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(token);
    }
  });

    const stripeTokenHandler = (token) => {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    const form = document.getElementById('new_job');
    const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    ["brand", "exp_month", "exp_year", "last4"].forEach(function(field) {
       addFieldToForm(form, token, field);
    });

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }

  function addFieldToForm(form, token, field) {
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', "user[card_" + field + "]");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.card[field]);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
  }
});
```

I actually wanted the stripe element form to display on heroku production as on development on localhost.

Comment: In which line is the error being detected?

Comment: not a  line in my code. in the inspects elemenrts, it adds this info =>       **(anonymous) @ application-cbd9d834…11b63dc56191d.js:35.**  And i think its the precompiled assets (precompile javascript).

Comment: [link] (http://jobbay.herokuapp.com/assets/application-cbd9d8348d6201b313a29b9cffdcbafeb803a001dfd8507b80d11b63dc56191d.js)   when you start counting from the last line upword, the error start from= the 16th line to downwards. here is a snippets of the 16th line. _where i have bolden is where the error starts from =>_  {this.App||(this.App={}),App.cable=ActionCable.createConsumer()}.call(this), **new Card({form:"form",container:".card",formSelectors:**